# In eclipse package explorer, how can I expand a tree in one click?

Tags: eclipse

For example, I have a folder structure like this:

```
src
└─test
    ├─java
       └─com
           └─google
              └─test
                  │  AllTests.java
```

in order to see file AllTests.java, I need to click many times to expand the tree. 
I'm wondering if there is an option as "expand all" to expand the tree in 1 click.

Answer (score 11):

You can avoid the hierarchical layout by using the flat package presentation (which is default):

[image: Screenshot]

If you typically just want to find the file which you have currently opened in the editor, then please activate editor linking:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! The package presentation option only apply to packages, not a plain folder structure.

Answer (score 8):

Check out with  `Shift + Numpad_multiply` for expanding all and  `Shft + Ctrl + Numpad_divide` to collapse all

Comment: Shft+Ctrl+Numpad_divide works, but Shift+Ctl+Numpad_multiply doesn't. any ideas?

Comment: @sakthisundar's Shift+Ctrl+Numpad_multiply didn't work for me either, but Shift+Numpad_multiply did.

Comment: By the way, this is better done in Navigator than Package Explorer - if you have referenced libraries under where you're expanding, it'll expand those too - and everything within them. Might take a while.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pressing `Numpad_Multiply` works for me for expanding all the subtree of the selected item in the package explorer, with Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse Juno and Mac OS X 10.7.5 you can expand with `Alt+Right`, but this expand everything, including methods and variables.